# How do I take the string returned from gen_results_table in PHP SDK and convert it to a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, quickbase

I'm using the Quickbase API via a PHP  SDK to call the *gen_results_table()* function and retrieve a javascript array. The multidimensional array returns as a string in PHP. Anyone know the best way to access the array? I currently have this as a start:

```
<?php

$rawdata = $qbconnect->gen_results_table($queries, '', '', '11.12.13', '', 'num-3' ) ;

?>
```

*var_dump($rawdata)* yields:

string(1377) "var qdb_numcols = 3; var qdb_numrows = 10; var qdb_heading = new Array(); qdb_heading[0] = "Year"; qdb_heading[1] = "Month"; qdb_heading[2] = "Total"; var qdb_data = new Array(); qdb_data[0] = new Array(); qdb_data[0][0] = "2013"; qdb_data[0][1] = "January"; qdb_data[0][2] = "$9.16"; qdb_data[1] = new Array(); qdb_data[1][0] = "2013"; qdb_data[1][1] = "January"; qdb_data[1][2] = "$64.80"; qdb_data[2] = new Array(); qdb_data[2][0] = "2013"; qdb_data[2][1] = "January"; qdb_data[2][2] = "$164.88"; "

```
<script>
var js_var = "<?php echo rawurlencode($rawdata); ?>";
document.write(unescape(js_var)) ;
</script>
```

*document.write(unescape(js_var))* yields:

var qdb_numcols = 3; var qdb_numrows = 1; var qdb_heading = new Array(); qdb_heading[0] = "Year"; qdb_heading[1] = "Month"; qdb_heading[2] = "Total"; var qdb_data = new Array(); qdb_data[0] = new Array(); qdb_data[0][0] = "2013"; qdb_data[0][1] = "January"; qdb_data[0][2] = "$9.16";

Now I just need a way to access what's stored in *js_var*.

Comment: just print `$rawdata` into a script tag?

Comment: you're probably going to want to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. It may not be the best practice but what I ended up doing is: `$rawdata1 = rawurlencode($rawdata) ;
file_put_contents($jscript,rawurldecode($rawdata1)) ;`

Comment: That definitely works as well. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is dump the raw data in your HTML code between `script` tags:

```
<script>
    <?php echo rawurlencode($rawdata); ?>

    console.log(qdb_numcols); // <-- the data is now available
</script>
```